# Installing Bakefile in Mac osx 10.11

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, bakefile

I have been trying to install **bakefile**(v0.2.9) in mac osx 10.11. Whenever I try to install bakefile using the dmg file I get `The installation failed.The installer could not install the software because there was no software found to install` error.

I even tried building it from the source code(v1.2.5.1 from github). I built it using the **sudo make** command.However **sudo make install** command throws `No rule to make target install`.

Is there any other way to install bakefile in macosx 10.11?

**Edit :** 
Finally I managed to install the bakefile 0.2.9 in osx 10.11. I can't use the latest version as it does not supports the bakefile we have been using  in our projects.

Though the installation is successful,I get the **segmentation fault 11** when I try to build the bakefiles(.bkl). Some of the forums suggested that  the problem could be associated with python 2.7. I followed all the steps needed to resolve the issue. But none of them helped.

I have been using python 2.7.11. How can I avoid this segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice against using the legacy 0.2.9 version.

> I even tried building it from the source code(v1.2.5.1 from github).

You didn’t, that’s the problem — you tried to build a very different version, 0.2.9 != 1.2.5.1. The relation between these two branches is explained at http://bakefile.org — they are incompatible and different.

If you want to build 0.2.9 from sources, you need to *download and build 0.2.9*.

If you want to use the 1.x version, you can download packaged “binary” version, as explained at https://github.com/vslavik/bakefile

P.S. You don’t need to, and shouldn’t, use `sudo` when installing somewhere you typically have access to, such as `/usr/local` on OS X.

Comment: @Slavik Thanks for the suggestion.With your advice I built bakefile for osx10.11. I have been facing some issues(updated above). Is the problem with the python or with the bakefile?

Comment: Possibly this: https://github.com/vslavik/bakefile/pull/49 — apply the patch, *regenerate with SWIG*, re-compile and re-install. This is ancient version, if you insist on using it, be prepared to do some basic debugging (which you're surely capable of) yourself. Better yet, *upgrade* your bakefiles and use the modern version.

Comment: @Slavik I finally built bitbake(v0.2.9) by applying the patch you mentioned. As you said I modified the bkl_c.i file,regenerated with SWIG and re-installed it. Now it's woking fine. Thanks a lot..